# How can I recover from accidental chown -R

Tags: permissions, chown

I am an Ubuntu newbie, and I accidentally typed `chown www-data:www-data * -R`.
After a while, I tried to restart, but my computer couldn't even start, saying:

```
# Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. 
# You will need to configure these yourself.
```

the command I executed is like this:

```
cd /home
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R  
sudo usermod -a -G www-data username
```

Is there any way I can get out of this mess? Thank you

Comment: That command shouldn't do anything besides complaining about missing parameters. What command did you actually execute?

Comment: @DavidFoerster 
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R followd by
sudo usermod -a -G www-data username

Comment: Ok, can you edit that into your question? The working directory of that command is relevant too.

Comment: I updated the question @DavidFoerster

Comment: Good. Do you remember the working directory when you run that command?

Comment: @DavidFoerster - I was at /home. At this point, I have reinstalled ubuntu but I think the answer will be beneficial for the community. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try booting using advanced settings, and do a system restore...there is an option for that on the ubuntu bootloader menu

Answer (score 1):

If you accidentally change the ownership of everything in `/home` and it contains only home directories named after their respective owners, then you can revert that change as root like this:

```bsh
cd /home
chown root:root .
for f in *; do
  case "$f" in
    lost+found) owner=root:root;;
    *) owner="$f:";;
  esac
  chown -R "$owner" "$f"
done
```

There may be a few corner cases like configurational or temporary files of some subsystem like X.org or Pulse inside those directories, which should be owned by root or some system account, but they shouldn't be too much of a problem.